# Passing ID from one function to another with return

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like to validate and set a ID for a collection in firebase. Right now i am just trying to get an id number back from a collections query and send it to the function that needs it. Here is the function that needs the id#.

```
const data = lastCustIdGrab(); console.log(`Last number ${data}`);
```

This is the return sender. I can get the document Id in the console log but can't figure how to send it back.

```
exports.lastCustIdGrab = () => {
  db.collection('Customers')
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  .limit(1);
  .get()
    .then((data) => {
        let DOC = data.docs[0];
        let ID = DOC.id;
        console.log("LOOOP ",ID);
   return ID;
})}
```

This gets me the id in the LOOOP output but won't return it! I know i can return data as i have tested with the arbitrary code below and it works. The return sends it back to be console logged in the "last number" output properly.

```
exports.lastCustIdGrab = () => {
let ID = 12345;
return ID;
```

}

So I'm sure that i am just missing something simple. Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `lastCustIdGrab` function you need to return [the promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining), as follows:

```
exports.lastCustIdGrab = () => {
  return db.collection('Customers')   // <== See return 
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  .limit(1);
  .get()
    .then((data) => {
        let DOC = data.docs[0];
        let ID = DOC.id;
        console.log("LOOOP ",ID);
        return ID;
    });
}
```

**AND** you should note that the `lastCustIdGrab` function is asynchronous and returns a Promise, which means that you need to do:

```
lastCustIdGrab()
.then(data => {
   console.log(`Last number ${data}`);
});
```

Comment: Renaud-> you my friend are awesome! Had tried the return on the db but did not even think of having to wait on the promise return! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`.get()` is asynchronous, and in your method you're not returning the promise. So even though the `then()` is executing, the value returned from the promise's resolve isn't being returned to `lastCustIdGrab()` invocation because the promise is never returned. So (switching it up to use async/await) try this:

```js
exports.lastCustIdGrab = async () => {
  let data = await db.collection('Customers')
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
  .limit(1)
  .get();

  let DOC = data.docs[0];
  let ID = DOC.id;
  return ID;
  }
}
```

And in your invocation wait for the promise to resolve to ensure error handling and method completion:

```js
const data = await lastCustIdGrab();
```